# Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the "WebServiceQuery" language

Tags: java, исключения, jasperreports, jasperstudio

Вылетает Exception при компиляции jrxml
jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MasterReportjrxml" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f19ea27c-765b-40cb-a3db-c41a42dcaf85">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="RESTReportAdapter"/>
    <queryString language="WebServiceQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
  "getparameters" : { },
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "expression" : "id"
  }, {
    "name" : "fullName",
    "expression" : "fullName"
  }, {
    "name" : "phoneNumber",
    "expression" : "phoneNumber"
  }, {
    "name" : "birthDay",
    "expression" : "birthDay"
  } ],
  "options" : {
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "rootPath" : "",
    "baseUrl" : "/Master"
  },
  "headersMap" : { },
  "queryData" : "",
  "GETParameters" : { }
}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fullName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="phoneNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="birthDay" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="72">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="595" height="92" backcolor="#006699" uuid="7ead9487-d226-49cb-8e79-1585733d5e38"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="234" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a15cda4d-5919-4608-9202-6c6004842cd4"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="34" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Report]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="395" y="43" width="180" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ff3afcad-664a-4703-835a-cec5fc3c3da3"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="14" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[information about masters]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="13"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="20" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666" uuid="a3559868-a8f2-4420-a76c-c477dbebe95f"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="141" height="21" uuid="9a4ed28a-9f4b-44c0-a8f7-f5a738b260ca">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="ddf1f4b5-c4e4-4ffd-bcbe-7e85ecd0c8ec"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="141" y="0" width="138" height="21" uuid="05c1bafd-d2a2-4f5b-9812-a27402957698">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="054081ff-c425-4b43-bb8f-f836046c1f32"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[fullName]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="279" y="0" width="138" height="21" uuid="14d4c95e-ddb3-4393-8a79-0273a75fa163">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9a0c60cf-18f7-4e04-b2a8-3aa5d3c2c8ef"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[phoneNumber]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="417" y="0" width="138" height="21" uuid="9b81903e-e1dc-4666-8376-83e32f0b8f1f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="61bb5b62-70e7-41fc-8851-c7db57a611d2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[birthDay]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="60">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="19" width="555" height="1" uuid="c124dd98-ae38-4530-86a3-2b9376e2e3ad"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="141" height="30" uuid="122d74a7-796c-4aaf-b700-a664d90522b4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="ddf1f4b5-c4e4-4ffd-bcbe-7e85ecd0c8ec"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="141" y="30" width="138" height="30" uuid="f22b5570-2a41-4e7c-a435-115e91e24c03">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="054081ff-c425-4b43-bb8f-f836046c1f32"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fullName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="279" y="30" width="138" height="30" uuid="684108ce-3806-4cd5-a57c-80dcd9de8449">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="9a0c60cf-18f7-4e04-b2a8-3aa5d3c2c8ef"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phoneNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="417" y="30" width="138" height="30" uuid="b42ed162-2060-4c90-bcb1-94befc2c41d3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="61bb5b62-70e7-41fc-8851-c7db57a611d2"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{birthDay}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="17">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="dda3015d-19f4-4085-8257-eb37bab4d508"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="515" y="4" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="fc93bc25-3e0a-4273-ab3f-4f6563d3950a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13" uuid="de57b74e-e504-4c58-87cc-16f5f33dcd6d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

java - создание PDF отчета:

```
public void generate() {
    try {
      String jrxmlFileName = "C:\\Users\\Alexander\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\MasterReportjrxml.jrxml";
      String jasperFileName = "C:/reports/C1_report.jasper";
      String pdfFileName = "C:/reports/C1_report.pdf";

      JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jrxmlFileName, jasperFileName);
      JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFileName, null);
      JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, pdfFileName);


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
```

используется плагин WebServiceDataSource

Comment: В java коде , больше ничего нет, я так понимаю надо добавить адаптер для webservice, каким образом это можно сделать?